# RASA: How to build mixed-Initiative conversations?

Tags: rasa, rasa-core, chatscript, conversational-ai, conversational-design

I ask a question/help request regarding how to set-up a mixed-initiative chatbot in RASA

For **mixed-initiative** conversational bot, I mean a chat-bot thatallows both

- **User-initiative**: The bot simply reply to user requests(I also call this: **pull-mode**).
- **Bot-initiative**: the bot is "proactive", initiating new unsolicited conversation/topic with the user (I call this: **push-mode**).
  The bot "pushes" could be something like a question to user or a user-feedback request getting some information:

  - Related to the previous conversational flow (so "dynamic" and dependent from the context of current dialog),
  - And/or part of a "scripted" sequence of pre-fixed step-by-step bot-utterances (stimulus/question to user). In that sense I guess that a solution could be a "static" flow-path made by some sort of RASA rules/forms combination (see later).

---

##### Gambits: the ChatScript bot-initiative approach

The bot-initiative static steps are one of tools to design a conversation in [ChatScript](https://github.com/ChatScript/ChatScript) old good chatbot scripting language/engine. These are called *gambits*. *Are the story the chatbot wants to tell on a subject or the conversation the chatbot is trying to steer the user into*. See definition/explanation [here](https://github.com/ChatScript/ChatScript/blob/master/WIKI/ChatScript-Basic-User-Manual.md#fast-overview-of-topic-files-sample-rawdataharrychildhoodtop).

Here below a ChatScript code example where the bot start a conversation about the school topic:

```yaml
topic: ~school [school university learn]

t: Where do you go to school?
    a: (Rochester) That's a great school.

t: I go to Harvard.

t: What is your major?

t: I am studying finance.
```

At run-time (`<` is the bot, `>` is the user):

```
< Where do you go to school?
> At liceo Leonardo Da Vinci in Genova,
< I go to Harvard.
> Wow! Super!
< What is your major?
> Electronic engineering...
< I am studying finance.
```

---

##### How to implement ChatScript gambits in RASA?

how can I realize such a bot-driven conversation in RASA? I'm a bit
confused about the how-to. Ok, a RASA rule could trigger the first utterance and afterward I could design the flow with stories examples? Or with a RASA form?

---

I'd like to realize a mixed-initiative scenario where:

- Every time any user can ask the bot for faqs/news etc. (pull mode)
- the (expert) patient is able to communicate himself his status  (pull mode)
- But also the bot need to collect some mentioned info (filling slots like, for example in a patient monitoring healthcare app, the medical-relevant parameters, explicitly asking question to user (push mode).

I'm confused regarding how to implement this in RASA. How to code an
info collection dialog without a strict / boring sequence of slots
mangling in a RASA form?

Maybe a crontab (external) event, following suggestion here https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/reaching-out-to-user could be used to inject a scheduled intent that trigger the conversational session, using a RASA rule. So far so good.

What is not clear to me is how to manage the "slot-filling"-like data collection in a natural conversation way that possibly allow a mixed initiative where the user spontaneously give to the user some data, or the bot ask data to user, if (some) session data are missing.

I know I can roughly realize all this with a RASA form but I believe this solution is limiting because inside a form the sequence of questions (to collect slots) is fixed. Maybe i'd prefer to have a more natural mixed-initiative turn-taking where the user could interact with the bot asking stuff and with digressions, but the bot would collect data explicitly asking in case.

Any suggestion/help about how to do all this in RASA?

Thanks!
Giorgio